# Can I instantiate an ActiveX Control directly in a Delphi app, either via TOleContainer or some other way?

Tags: delphi, activex

The TOleContainer  can of course, insert OLE Objects like Word Documents.  But it doesn't seem to work for ActiveX.  I know, of course, about Delphi's IDE ability to create an ActiveX wrapper.  What if I want to create a control without creating a wrapper and installing it into the IDE, at runtime?

The control is registered, so [unlike this question, I don't need registration-free com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974423/how-can-i-dynamically-instantiate-an-activex-control-from-an-ocx-file). I just need some idea, or some sample, of how dynamic ActiveX Containers are started.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The  [`TOleContainer`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.OleCtnrs.TOleContainer) works with ActiveX controls, you only need pass the proper `ProgID` of the Activex control to the [`CreateObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.OleCtnrs.TOleContainer.CreateObject) method and then using late-binding access the properties of the ActiveX.

Check this sample which create a Windows Media Player ActiveX control inside of a TOleContainer in runtime.

```
OleContainer1.CreateObject('Wmplayer.OCX.7', False);
OleContainer1.OleObject.URL:='F:\Music\Iron Maiden - The number of the beast.mp3';
OleContainer1.OleObject.Controls.Play;
```

Comment: Ooh. Iron Maiden - haven't heard them for years. Have to go retro on my play list now. :-)